# Why can't I query more than 1 post type at a time?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I have a custom post types called **publications**. I want to retrieve all the **pages** and **publications**. (I'm also filtering by taxonomy, but that's not what is creating the problem)

```
$args= array(
        'post_type'=>array('publications', 'page')
        );
query_posts($args);
```

The above only returns pages, not publications.
If I remove 'page' from the array and leave

```
'post_type'=>array('publications')
```

then the publications are returned.

Its seems like I cannot query more than one post type at a time, contrary to what the codex explains [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Type_.26_Status_Parameters).

I've tried `'post_type' = 'any'` with the same results; only the pages are returned. Using `WP_Query` also yielded the same results.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in WP 3.1 rc3?

Comment: [resolved] Translation of custom post types had to be enabled in WPML settings. [here's how](http://forum.wpml.org/topic.php?id=1928)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@Bundarr:**

Testing the following basic example as a standalone file it looks like it works as expected and not as you are reporting:

```
<?php

include '../wp-load.php';
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$q = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'=>array('publications', 'page')
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
));
echo "SQL: {$q->request}\n";
foreach($q->posts as $post) {
  echo "{$post->post_name} - {$post->post_type}\n";
}
```

So, I can only assume that you have some plugins or theme code that is somehow blocking?

Or maybe it is as simple as missing a `'posts_per_page' => -1` argument and thus only displaying a limited number and making it seem like it's not working?  With `'posts_per_page'` the query would look like this *(-1 means 'no limit'):*

```
$q = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'=>array('publications', 'page')
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
));
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for pointing me in the right direction. By looking at the SQL statement it is clear that the problem is coming from the WPML plugin - custom post_types dont have mutilingual enabled as of yet. T

Comment: @Bundarr - Cool. Glad to help.  Submit a [trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/) then?

Comment: It's my oversight. Ive pointed to the solution in a comment to my question.